# PhpStorm .phtml formatting issue

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have problems with PhpStorm auto formating feature. I can't get it to format `<?php if(...): ?>` and   `<?php endif; ?>` correctly.

This code for example is perfectly formatted ...

```
<td class="align-right">
    <?php if ($featureSet->grossPrices): ?>
        <?=$this->e(formatPrice($cartItem->totalGrossPrice / $cartItem->amount))?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?=$this->e(formatPrice($cartItem->totalNetPrice / $cartItem->amount))?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

... but the autoformatter will change it so it look like this:

```
<td class="align-right">
    <?php if ($featureSet->grossPrices): ?>
        <?= $this->e(formatPrice($cartItem->totalGrossPrice / $cartItem->amount)) ?><?php else: ?>
        <?= $this->e(formatPrice($cartItem->totalNetPrice / $cartItem->amount)) ?><?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

Do you have any suggestions? I really love PhpStorm. This is literally the only the only issue I have with it, but it really freaks me out -.-

Comment: have you checked your preferences? I've manually set all my spaces, brackets, conversions, quotes etc. etc. in Settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP

Comment: yes I did. But I could not find an option like "inserte linebreak after closing php tag"

Comment: I set my code style with "Set from... PSR1/PSR2" and I get entirely different results (it merely adds the spaces after `<?=` and before `?>`) so I can at least I can confirm the setting exists. Now we just need to find it :)

Comment: @Benjamin Please post screenshots of your Code Style settings for PHP. Ideally just use `Set from...` and use `PSR1/PSR2` option (you can create new scheme and test it there)

Comment: Ok, I found a solution: In the HTML code style settings the option `Keep line breaks` was disabled and caused this behavior. Though I think even with this option turned off it should not align the PHP tags like this..

Comment: Glad you got it. Feel free to post your findings as answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
In the HTML code style settings the option `Keep line breaks` was disabled and caused this behavior.
Though I think even with this option turned off it should not align the PHP tags like this.

I submitted an issue to the PhpStorm devs:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-44274